# H2 database script cannot be imported into MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, h2

I have created a local H2 database which I always opened in MySQL mode to insert data. Now, I want to export it with `SCRIPT`, in order to import it with `phpMyAdmin` on a remote MySQL database on a remote server. I get the following:

```
SET LOCK_MODE 3;
;             
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS SA SALT '...' HASH '...' ADMIN;           
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.RAWVALUEITEM(
    LANGUAGE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 1,
    RAWVALUE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 99,
    STRIPPED VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 96
);
...
```

Unfortunately, `phpMyAdmin` import is not happy:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'LOCK_MODE'
```

When I manually remove the `set` instruction, I get further errors:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS SA SALT '...' HASH '...' at line 1
```

The code I use to export the database as a script is:

```
public static final String DB_DIR_LOCATION = "E:/Temp/FWDB/";
public static final String H2_CONNECTION = "jdbc:h2:file:"
    + DB_DIR_LOCATION + "FWDB_PHP_TEST" + "Mode=MySQL;IFEXISTS=TRUE";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = DriverManager.
        getConnection(H2_CONNECTION, "sa", "");

    PreparedStatement ps;

    ps = conn.prepareStatement("SCRIPT TO 'E:/Temp/FWDB/FWDB_EXPORT.gz' " 
        + "COMPRESSION GZIP");
    ps.execute();

}
```

How can generate a script from my DB which will be imported successfully by phpMyAdmin on my remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL script generated by the [SCRIPT TO command](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) is not cross-platform. A better solution might be to use a database tool such as the [SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin](http://dbcopyplugin.sourceforge.net/) or another [database tool](http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools).